# MOSS OOB Workflows Throwing Errors - The workflow failed to start due to an internal error

Tags: workflow

[image]

I have a SiteCollection which has subsites and evertime i try to assign a workflow on a documentlevel or list level i get the error message **"**The workflow failed to start due to an internal error"****

I tried deleting the workflows and recreate then and i tried deactivating the OOB features at Site Collection Level and reactivated it but i still get the Error, has anybody come across similar issues.

Turned ON the Verbose Logging but there nothing specific in that Any suggestions.

Comment: did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

After bumping into this myself, here are my findings.

- This happens apparently a lot in SharePoint 2007, but also in SharePoint 2010, for similar reasons
- We can enable verbose logging for workflows (CA, Diagnostic Logging) and even [enable workflow debugging](http://blogs.technet.com/b/victorbutuza/archive/2009/02/26/how-to-enable-workflow-tracing-debug.aspx). However, as the workflow never really starts, there will be little or none relevant log entries.
- This is often related to caching or orphaned content types, or otherwise conflicts resolved by re-enabling features.

Now as for the actual (individual) solutions, in order of complexity:

- Disable the "Workflows" feature and re-enable it [[ref](http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2011/09/23/sharepoint-workflow-error-workflow-is-automatically-cancelled.aspx)]
- Restart owstimer and IIS (if it's an option) [[ref](http://blog.henryong.com/2011/04/21/the-workflow-failed-to-start-due-to-an-internal-error/)] (comment)
- Delete workflow assembly cache at C:\Users\profile name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache [[ref](http://sharepointbyfox.blogspot.se/2014/05/the-workflow-failed-to-start-due-to.html)]   [[ref](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/03/27/tip-clearing-the-spd-workflow-assembly-cache.aspx)]
- Remove orphaned content types [[ref](http://blogs.architectingconnectedsystems.com/blogs/cjg/archive/2012/03/05/The-workflow-failed-to-start-due-to-an-internal-error.aspx)]
- Stop workflow timer service [[ref](http://ybbest.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/how-to-fix-workflow-failed-to-start-in-sharepoint2010/)]
- Using collaboration template instead of publishing [[ref](http://umakanthn.blogspot.se/2007/06/workflow-failed-to-start-due-to.html)]
- Delete and re-provision the list (good fix for development environments)
- Disable, Uninstall and Re-enable all the workflow features [[ref](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f76ca719-f44d-458a-8508-83f2853ed379/the-workflow-failed-to-start-due-to-an-internal-error?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy)] (script below)

  $siteUrl = "http://sitecollectionurl.com"

  #deactivate and uninstall

  #OffWFCommon

  stsadm -o deactivatefeature -id C9C9515D-E4E2-4001-9050-74F980F93160 -url $siteUrl -force
  stsadm -o uninstallfeature -id C9C9515D-E4E2-4001-9050-74F980F93160 -force

  #ExpirationWorkflow

  stsadm -o deactivatefeature -id C85E5759-F323-4EFB-B548-443D2216EFB5 -url $siteUrl -force
  stsadm -o uninstallfeature -id C85E5759-F323-4EFB-B548-443D2216EFB5 -force

  #ReviewWorkflows

  stsadm -o deactivatefeature -id 02464C6A-9D07-4F30-BA04-E9035CF54392 -url  $siteUrl -force
  stsadm -o uninstallfeature -id 02464C6A-9D07-4F30-BA04-E9035CF54392 -force

  #SignaturesWorkflow

  stsadm -o deactivatefeature -id 6C09612B-46AF-4B2F-8DFC-59185C962A29 -url  $siteUrl -force
  stsadm -o uninstallfeature -id 6C09612B-46AF-4B2F-8DFC-59185C962A29 -force

  #translationWorkflow

  stsadm -o deactivatefeature -id C6561405-EA03-40A9-A57F-F25472942A22 -url  $siteUrl -force
  stsadm -o uninstallfeature -id C6561405-EA03-40A9-A57F-F25472942A22 -force

  #install & activate

  #OffWFCommon

  stsadm -o installfeature -name offwfcommon -force
  stsadm -o activatefeature -id C9C9515D-E4E2-4001-9050-74F980F93160 -url $siteUrl -force

  #ExpirationWorkflow

  stsadm -o installfeature -name Expirationworkflow -force
  stsadm -o activatefeature -id C85E5759-F323-4EFB-B548-443D2216EFB5 -url $siteUrl -force

  #ReviewWorkflows

  stsadm -o installfeature -name ReviewWorkflows -force
  stsadm -o activatefeature -id 02464C6A-9D07-4F30-BA04-E9035CF54392 -url $siteUrl -force

  #SignaturesWorkflow

  stsadm -o installfeature -name SignaturesWorkflow -force
  stsadm -o activatefeature -id 6C09612B-46AF-4B2F-8DFC-59185C962A29 -url $siteUrl -force

  #TranslationWorkflow

  stsadm -o installfeature -name Translationworkflow -force
  stsadm -o activatefeature -id C6561405-EA03-40A9-A57F-F25472942A22 -url  $siteUrl -force